# Ubuntu 16.04, install evince via snap, but no service via dbus

Tags: emacs, evince

I am running 16.04 with evince GNOME Document Viewer 3.20.1
Now evince 4.X displays hyperlinks as pop-up windows, which is very useful for documents with equations.
I installed evince 4.4 via snap
sudo install snap
and even linked the binaries to /usr/local/bin

```
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/evince /usr/local/bin/evince
```

However the daemon does not start!

```
snap services just shows
Service            Startup  Current  Notes
cups.cups-browsed  enabled  active   -
cups.cupsd         enabled  active   -
```

but I need the
org.gnome.evince.Daemon.service
so
I changed the line

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.gnome.evince.Daemon
Exec=/usr/lib/evince/evinced
SystemdService=evince.service
```

to

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.gnome.evince.Daemon
Exec=/snap/evince/current/usr/libexec/evinced
SystemdService=evince.service
```

but it did not help
running

```
/snap/evince/current/usr/libexec/evinced
```

resulted in

```
/snap/evince/current/usr/libexec/evinced: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /snap/evince/current/usr/libexec/evinced)
```

which is odd since I thought the idea of snap is, to have a self-contained binary without external dependencies.
I have no glibc 2.34 installed and rather prefer not to mess up my 16.04 distribution

the point is I need evinced to run, so that Emacs is able to communicate between the latex source file and the pdf file displayed by evince (forward and inverse search from source to pdf)
any ideas?
thanks in advance
Uwe Brauer

Comment: Hi Uwe, one of the criticism on snapd is that it makes this kind of inter-process communication fail. I don't know whether snap is to blame here, but it's likely; I'd recommend just using the native evince. Now here's the other problem: snap got better (and so did the native evince) in Ubuntu over the last seven years – but you're still on Ubuntu 16.04, which at most receives security updates anymore. So, I think the *honestly best-intended advice* I can give is to update your Ubuntu and use the native evince, if you need an evince that can communicate with other applications

Comment: you're right that the idea is that "snaps" are self-contained, but that means the binaries inside depend on other binaries inside the same snap – which is why you can't call them without setting up an environment that loads exactly these dependencies when needed. And that's what `snap` does! It prepares an environment from an archive (or directory) that is independent of the rest of your system. That does mean you can't "directly" run the executables from within, usually.

Comment: But when I try to call 
```
/snap/evince/current/usr/libexec/evinced
```
what is the right configuration? Because I obtain
```
/snap/evince/current/usr/libexec/evinced: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /snap/evince/current/usr/libexec/evinced)
```

Comment: concerning uprgrading: yes I need to do this, but after a trip I will start soon.

Comment: you simply cannot meaningfully execute that program from your native environment. You need to go through snap. If you plan on upgrading, I'd put off solving this for after the upgrade.

Comment: you say: you need to go through snap, but how?

Comment: if it's not in /snap/bin, then the answer is "it's probably not currently possible"; you'd need to export the functionality by rolling your own snap package, and I *really* don't see how that's worth the effort here.

Comment: I just did, please check

Comment: @Uwe ..... Great