# Ubuntu 20 LTS, install evince via snap, but hyperlinks not correctly displayed in the pop-up window (the window is empty)

Tags: evince

while I successfully installed evince, via snap for Ubuntu 16.04
(see [Ubuntu 16.04, install evince via snap, but no service via dbus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/755478/ubuntu-16-04-install-evince-via-snap-but-no-service-via-dbus?noredirect=1#comment1438828_755478))
I run into a problem when I try to do the same for a friend using Ubuntu 20.04.
The installed works as expected, but when I open evince, via /snap/bin/evince
and then a pdf file that contains hyperrefs the pop-up window pops up as it does in my Ubuntu 16.04, but the pop-up window is **empty**
The message in the command line is

```
infinite surface is not supported.
```

I have no idea what this is supposed to mean.

any help is strongly appreciated.

Uwe Brauer

Comment: Uwe, may I note that you now say you successfully installed evince as per your other question -- but that question remains unanswered and yet it claims you are not able to run evince. Do you know you can [self-anwer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) the question, it is encouraged and you can also accept your own answer after 48 hours?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, on Laptop1 with Ubuntu 16.04 snap evince runs but evinced cannot be called. So nothing can be done.
On Laptop2 with Ubuntu 20.04, the hyperlinks are not correctly displayed as pop-ups, that is why I asked a different question. 
Concerning the error message:
```
(evince:18209): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:49:27.887: infinite surface size not supported
```
I could send a screenshot if this is helpful?

Comment: please put all that to the question.

Comment: It seems, that after a reboot, evince works now without problems the hyperlinks are correctly shown as pop-up. So I would like to put this question on hold, and then in 1 or 2 days close it. Is this ok?

Comment: I think that someone can profit from the answer, even as simple as "after reboot (file-local) link pop-ups work". Some one can have the same problem, and also some installation procedures and/or instructions may be improved if your experience is confirmed independently. Let me recall that [self-answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) are encouraged! But update the question please (full error message etc.).